# Null error on loading image from php in card swiper

Tags: php, android, flutter, api, dart

This is the home page function in which I added an image slider(card swiper) for the carousel image and the images are loaded from the PHP network but the images aren't able to load and throw the null error and also its body is loaded in next function the code is below:

```dart
  class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    Home({
    Key? key,
    required this.body,
    }) : super(key: key);
    final body;

    @override
    _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }

    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    Future<List<ModelEbook>>? getSlider;
    List<ModelEbook> listSlider = [];

    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSlider = fetchEbook(listSlider);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getSlider,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ModelEbook>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              //displays data here
              return Column(
                children: [
                  //Slider
                  // ImageSlider(),
                  Container(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: getSlider,
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<List<ModelEbook>> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                          //Create design in here

                          return SizedBox(
                            height: 27.0.h,
                            child: Swiper(
                              autoplay: true,
                              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                // ModelEbook _ = snapshot.data![index];
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Stack(
                                        children: [
                                          ClipRRect(
                                            child: Image.network(
                                              listSlider[index].photo,
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              width: 100.0.w,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Container();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),


                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else {
              print('error');
              return Text('error');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

this is the body of the above function in which I also added a customized app bar and bottom navigation bar:

```dart
 class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
     bool _folded = true;

     get currentIndex => null;

     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        color: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/icons/menu.svg",
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 110),
                  child: Container(
                    width: _folded ? 52 : 250,
                    height: getProportionateScreenHeight(50),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.brown.shade300.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(-4, 0),
                          ),
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(4, 0),
                          ),
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.brown.shade300.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(-4, 0),
                          ),
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(4, 0),
                          ),
                        ]),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                            child: !_folded
                                ? TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: 'Search Book, Author,Genre ',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54,
                                        fontFamily:
                                            GoogleFonts.oregano().fontFamily,
                                      ),
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : null,
                          ),
                        ),
                        AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                          child: Material(
                            type: MaterialType.transparency,
                            child: InkWell(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(_folded ? 32 : 0),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(32),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_folded ? 32 : 0),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(32),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                      _folded
                                          ? "assets/icons/search.svg"
                                          : "assets/icons/close.svg",
                                      height: getProportionateScreenHeight(18),
                                      color: Colors.black54),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _folded = !_folded;
                                  });
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            
            Expanded(
              child: Home(
                body: currentIndex,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BottomDrawer(),
            ),
          
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the error shown after running the above command
[image]

and this is the error shown on the emulator after running the above command

[image]

```dart
Future<List<ModelEbook>> fetchEbook(List<ModelEbook> fetch) async 
    {
    print(
      "baseUrl ${ApiConstant().baseUrl + ApiConstant().api + 
    ApiConstant().latest}");
     var request = await Dio()
      .get(ApiConstant().baseUrl + ApiConstant().api + 
    ApiConstant().latest);

    for (Map<String, dynamic> ebook in request.data) {
    fetch.add(
      ModelEbook(
        id: ebook['id'],
        title: ebook['title'],
        photo: ebook['photo'],
        description: ebook['description'],
        catId: ebook['cat_id'],
        statusNews: ebook['status_newsNews'],
        pdf: ebook['pdf'],
        date: ebook['date'],
        authorName: ebook['author_name'],
        publisherName: ebook['publisher_name'],
        pages: ebook['pages'],
        language: ebook['language'],
        rating: ebook['rating'],
        free: ebook['free'], 
      ),
    );
    print("checkEbookFromDB ${ebook['photo']}");
    }
    return fetch;
    }

    class ApiConstant {
  String baseUrl = "http://i.p address(here)/ebookapp/";
  String api = "api.php?";
  String slider = "slider";
  String latest = "latest";
```

Comment: First of all, you need to check the image link is working in the browser or not.

Comment: its loaded from php

Comment: can you share the JSON response that comes from the API??

Comment: I added the API part

Comment: class ApiConstant {
  String baseUrl = "http://ip/ebookapp/";
  String api = "api.php?";
  String slider = "slider";
  String latest = "latest";

Comment: Please share more details. Is this really related to PHP itself? You haven't shared any code for this. Or is this a pure Android problem, as the PHP part itself is working as expected?

Comment: no need to call `getSlider` 2x, use one and check if snapshot contains data,

Comment: what is the response of the ebook['photo'] in JSON??

if it is like URL then flutter side problem or you need to convert into URL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call twice API to get the same data, use parent snapshot for inner child and follow `FutureBuilder` structure. Calling future initState doesn't provide data in this case, you can create another `async` method to handle it, but this will be simple, don't need to use  `initState`

```dart
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchEbook(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ModelEbook>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                snapshot.hasData) {
              //displays data here
              return Column(
                children: [
                  //Slider
                  // ImageSlider(),
                  Container(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 27.0.h,
                      child: Swiper(
                        autoplay: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          // ModelEbook _ = snapshot.data![index];
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    ClipRRect(
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        snapshot.data![index].photo,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        width: 100.0.w,
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else {
              print('error');
              return Text('error');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is better to return nullable list from `fetchEbook` because of uncertain future.
More about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: future: fetchEbook(), shows positional argument error

Comment: Pass empty list for your case, or declear the one as you did on state level  `List<ModelEbook> listSlider = [];` and pass on future `fetchEbook (listSlider )`

Comment: it's now only loading with that circular indicator but nothing be able to fetch from the network what will it possibly be where have I done wrong also after loading completed its written error on screen

Comment: possibility exits , you can print/debug data  on console , and do not use `setState` inside futureBuilder